# How can I create an Infographic Timeline with CSS jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, timeline, jquery-steps

I want to create something like this image: [Infographic Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz3IP.png)
Can anyone help me with this, maybe some info, some examples.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I am searching for any idea or example. If I will not find, I will try to build it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://venngage.com/blog/how-to-create-a-timeline-infographic-in-6-steps/)

> I found this where it is well described. Please go through the link.

Comment: The project which will be exported in the final stage is in PDF or PNG formats.